# Установка библиотек с Composer

Tags: php, composer, packagist

здравствуйте! Решил установить в свой небольшой проект один пакет из packagist, но заметил что вместе с запрашиваемым пакетом установились также парочка других. Это нормально или это маркетинг? После исследовании src источника мне показалось что нужная мне библиотека не зависит от тех "непрошенных" пакетов. Это обычная практика или я что-то не понимаю?

```
user@debian:~/www/simple$ composer require voku/anti-xss
Using version ^2.1 for voku/anti-xss
./composer.json has been updated
Loading composer repositories with package information
Updating dependencies (including require-dev)
Package operations: 6 installs, 0 updates, 0 removals
  - Installing symfony/intl (v3.3.2): Loading from cache
  - Installing symfony/polyfill (v1.4.0): Loading from cache
  - Installing ircmaxell/password-compat (v1.0.4): Loading from cache
  - Installing paragonie/random_compat (v2.0.10): Loading from cache
  - Installing voku/portable-utf8 (3.1.21): Loading from cache
  - Installing voku/anti-xss (2.1.7): Loading from cache
symfony/intl suggests installing ext-intl (to use the component with locales other than "en")
paragonie/random_compat suggests installing ext-libsodium (Provides a modern crypto API that can be used to generate random bytes.)
voku/portable-utf8 suggests installing ext-intl (Use Intl for best performance)
Writing lock file
Generating autoload files
user@debian:~/www/simple$
```

Comment: А показать composer.json не хотите?

Comment: @Visman поправил свой вопрос.

Comment: У `voku/anti-xss` в зависимостях стоит `voku/portable-utf8` https://github.com/voku/anti-xss/blob/master/composer.json#L26 , а у того `symfony/polyfill`. Дальше не смотрел.

Comment: @Visman ах вот оно что, не сообразил. Спасибо!